# Getting a second parameter based on the first parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I have a task where my Jenkins job needs two parameters for build. The first specifies the application name and can be either QA, Dev, Prod etc and the second is a server which is dependent on the first one.

Example: If I chose the app name as QA, the second parameter should display values like QAServer1, QAServer2, QAServer3.

I'm using `Active Choices Plugin` (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) to get this done but facing an problem in fetching the second parameter contents.

Snapshots:
[image]

For obtaining the second parameter, I've written a Groovy code which reads the respective files of the selected first parameter and gets the details.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import hudson.model.*
def Appliname = System.getenv("APPNAME")
//println Appliname
def list1 = []
def directoryName = "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/JSONSTest"
def fileSubStr = Appliname
def filePattern = ~/${fileSubStr}/
def directory = new File(directoryName)
def findFilenameClosure =
{
   if (filePattern.matcher(it.name).find())
   {
      def jsoname = it.name
      def jsoname1 = jsoname.reverse().take(9).reverse()
      list1.add(jsoname1.substring(1,4))
      String listAsString =  "[\'${list1.join("', '")}\']"
      println "return"+listAsString
   }

}
directory.eachFileRecurse(findFilenameClosure)
```

The above code will print the output as `return['QAServer1', 'QAServer2']` which i want to use it as input for the second parameter.

Snapshot of Second parameter:

[image]

Somehow the Groovy script is not being executed and second parameter value remains empty. How can i get this done dynamically. Am i following the right away to it. Kindly help me figure out. TIA

Comment: If you run the above script from out side, what do you get as output?

Comment: I'm able to get  the required output - `return['QAServer1', 'QAServer2']`  (which acts as an input to the second parameter - POP)

Comment: And you are finding that the same script is not working from jenkins parameters script?

Comment: Yes. that's right. but as per the documentation given for the plugin, only if-else clauses were used to fetch the second parameter contents based on the first parameter. In case you are trying out from your end, kindly write a groovy script which just gives the output as `return['QAServer1', 'QAServer2']` and try executing it. Still wondering what am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to try below change

From:

```
def findFilenameClosure =
{
   if (filePattern.matcher(it.name).find())
   {
      def jsoname = it.name
      def jsoname1 = jsoname.reverse().take(9).reverse()
      list1.add(jsoname1.substring(1,4))
      String listAsString =  "[\'${list1.join("', '")}\']"
      println "return"+listAsString
   }

}
directory.eachFileRecurse(findFilenameClosure)
```

To:

```
directory.eachFileRecurse {
       if (filePattern.matcher(it.name).find()) {
          def jsoname = it.name
          def jsoname1 = jsoname.reverse().take(9).reverse()
          list1.add(jsoname1.substring(1,4))      
       } 
    }
    return list1
```

Comment: you are not printing the output to fetch the contents

Comment: What do you have in the directory `JSONTest`?

Comment: `JSONTest` contains files with respective to the first parameter from which i parse it and get the values for the second parameter.

Comment: I've tried with your suggestions. i still dont see the values populating for the second parameter. I think Groovy script doesn't get executed there in that section.

Comment: @Dev, thank you for you patience, what do you see if the changed script is executed outside the jenkins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159339/discussion-between-dev-and-rao).